# The concept of creating a news feed

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, social-networking

I am currently using meteor.js for a social networking application that I am building. Currently I am struggling to find the best way to design a newsfeed for my users. Users are able to follow each other and create posts that should theoretically go to their followers. I have come up with two possible concepts that would work theoretically.

**I.** When a users makes a post the post goes into the global database which every user is subscribed and listening to, and whenever a post is added the user checks to see if the parent if they are following the parent of the post, and if they are they display it onto their newsfeed.

- This way seems horribly inefficient, but it is a way.

**II.** The other way would be for each user to have their own little "hub" or each user would just subscribe to and listen for change in the user's hub.

- This way seems better but I would have to do a for-loop on startup and subscribe to each user manually. Which may cause a slight delay on startup.

I am thinking that option two will work best, but I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to accomplish this task. Or if there is a standard way to go about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package. I'm doing something similar in my app and am using this package to essentially perform a join. In your case *people are following people* so when creating a publication that returns the set of users that a person is following you can at the same time return the union of all their posts.

Answer (score 0):

Building scalable feed technology is quite a hard problem to solve. With Meteor it is even harder because MongoDB doesn't lend itself very well for the storage of relational data, since it is a non-relational database, and creating publications that publish 'joined' data isn't straightforward. A lot of articles have been written about the problem of building scalable feed technology, have you seen my [article](http://blog.getstream.io/post/136611889848/building-news-feeds-activity-streams-with-meteor) on using Meteor in combination with Stream to build a solution that fits your needs?

Another route would be to use an open-source framework to create the backend for your feed technology. Have a look at [Stream-Framework](https://github.com/tschellenbach/stream-framework), the repositories README also has a great list of resources on building scalable feed technology.